valueerror: input 0 of layer "model_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(none, 128, 128, 3), found shape=(1, 224, 224, 3)
I am trying malaria detection using cnn model and Streamlit UI. But it show the error of "valueerror: input 0 of layer "model_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(none, 128, 128, 3), found shape=(1, 224, 224, 3)" for prediction .
the error msg:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), found shape=(1, 224, 224, 3)

Traceback:
File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\DiseasePredictionSystem\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 584, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Multiple Disease Prediction System\multiple disease pred.py", line 361, in <module>
    result = malaria_model.predict(final_image)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\DiseasePredictionSystem\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\HP\.conda\envs\DiseasePredictionSystem\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\input_spec.py", line 245, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(

This is the UI that I interacted with the CNN model:

This is the UI file that I used for the project.
malaria_model  = tf.keras.models.load_model(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Multiple Disease Prediction System\saved models\malaria.h5')
#Malaria Prediction Page
if selected == 'Malaria Disease Prediction':

     #page title
     st.title('Malaria Prediction using ML')
     
     IMG_SIZE = 224
     def resize_rescale(image):
          return tf.image.resize(image , (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))/255.0

     uploaded_image = st.file_uploader("Upload an image", type=["jpg", "png", "jpeg"])

     if uploaded_image is not None:
    # Display the uploaded image
         st.image(uploaded_image, caption="Uploaded Image", use_column_width=False)
         image = Image.open(uploaded_image)
    
    # Process the image (e.g., perform image analysis)

     if st.button("PREDICT"):
         image_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)

    # Convert the NumPy array to a TensorFlow tensor
         tensor_image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image_array)
         tensor_image = tf.expand_dims(tensor_image, axis=0)
    
         final_image = resize_rescale(tensor_image)

         result = malaria_model.predict(final_image)

         if result[0][0] < 0.5:
            st.header("Parasite")
         else:
            st.header("Uninfected")

This is the reference code file that I used for the project: https://github.com/kanchitank/Medibuddy-Smart-Disease-Predictor/blob/main/notebooks/malaria.ipynb

The error you're encountering is due to the shape mismatch between the image (1, 224, 224, 3) you uploaded and the input image shape (None, 128, 128, 3) that your CNN model expects. It looks like you're resizing your image before passing it to the model.
You can either resize your input images to (128, 128) or adjust your model to accept input images of size (224, 224).

@RabinBishwokarma I have to change input shape dimensions for fine-tuning with Keras . So I resized one of the image to 128*128 size but it still get the error. How can I try to adjust my model ?. Thank you so much for your answer.
